# Matching floating point numbers >= 100

Tags: regex, perl, floating-point, pattern-matching, string-matching

I'm reading a file line by line and want to get the lines starting with anything rather than AB and *containing a (at least) three digit floating point number* followed by a percentage sign (**i.e. any floating point number% greater than or equal to 100%**).

For instance:

```
AA whatevs 102.342% dontcare #MATCH
AB whatevs 102.342% dontcare #MISMATCH
AC whatevs 12.3042% dontcare #MISMATCH *
AD whatevs 102% dontcare #MATCH *
AE whatevs 2002.3042% dontcare #MATCH
AF whatevs 22.3021% dontcare #MISMATCH
AG whatevs 102.342 12.342% dontcare #MISMATCH **
```

I have the following regex solution so far, it does not capture `AD whatevs 102% dontcare` for obvious reason.

```
/^(?!AB).*\d{3}\.\d*%/
```

`/^(?!AB).*\d{3}\.?\d*%/` does not work either, since it matches `AF whatevs 22.3021% dontcare`.

I know that I can do it by splitting my regex into two sub regex based on the existence of `.`. However, I'd like to see if there is a single regex solution.

Comment: try this `/^(?!AB).*\d{3}(\.\d+)?%/` (not tested)

Answer (score 5):

As you've noticed, there are a lot of different ways to represent floating point numbers. You can use [`Regexp::Common::number`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::number) to handle them instead of rolling your own regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common qw(number);

while (<DATA>) {
    next if /^AB/;

    print if /\b$RE{num}{real}{-keep}%/ and $1 >= 100;
}

__DATA__
AA whatevs 102.342% dontcare #MATCH
AB whatevs 102.342% dontcare #MISMATCH
AC whatevs 12.3042% dontcare #MISMATCH *
AD whatevs 102% dontcare #MATCH *
AE whatevs 2002.3042% dontcare #MATCH
AF whatevs 22.3021% dontcare #MISMATCH
AG whatevs 102.342 12.342% dontcare #MISMATCH **
AH whatevs 1.02342E02% dontcare #MATCH
AI whatevs -102% dontcare #MISMATCH
```

#### Output:

```
AA whatevs 102.342% dontcare #MATCH
AD whatevs 102% dontcare #MATCH *
AE whatevs 2002.3042% dontcare #MATCH
AH whatevs 1.02342E02% dontcare #MATCH
```

I've added a negative number and an exponent to the data set to demonstrate the convenience of using `Regexp::Common`. Whether your data set includes such values or not, you don't have to tweak the regex.

Also note that it's easier to compare numbers when you treat them as numbers, not as a series of characters. `-100` is a three-digit number, but it's certainly not `>= 100`.

Answer (score 3):

The only trick is making sure that the 3 digit number isn't preceded by a decimal point.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^(?!AB).*\b(?<!\.)\d{3,}(?:\.\d*)?%/) {
        print;
    }
}
__DATA__
AA whatevs 102.342% dontcare #MATCH
AB whatevs 102.342% dontcare #MISMATCH due to AB
AC whatevs 12.3042% dontcare #MISMATCH
AD whatevs 102% dontcare #MATCH *
AE whatevs 2002.3042% dontcare #MATCH
AF whatevs 22.3021% dontcare #MISMATCH
AG whatevs 102.342 12.342% dontcare #MISMATCH
```

Outputs:

```
AA whatevs 102.342% dontcare #MATCH
AD whatevs 102% dontcare #MATCH *
AE whatevs 2002.3042% dontcare #MATCH
```

Comment: You're too fast! @Thanks Miller. I also fixed the question. Can you please add some comments to your regex... still trying to perceive.